# Next js, ReactDom.render is no longer supported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I just spun up a new Next JS app with Next 12.

I am getting this error on all page loads in the browser:

> Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use
> createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will
> behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more:
> https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

Next js's ReactDom.render is under the hood, how can I resolve this error?

Comment: It was Chakra ui. Update to 2.0.2 to get rid of this error.

Comment: please put your `_app.js` code for getting better answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me it was indeed Chakra. You need to Install the latest Chakra ui for NextJS

```
npm i @chakra-ui/react@2.0.0-next.3
```

Answer (score 10):

You may also get this warning if you've updated to React 18 and are using a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) setup in your Next.js app.

For this case, the issue has been addressed in this [PR](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/36664) in version `12.1.7-canary.2`. To fix it in your project simply update Next.js to version >=12.2.0.

```
npm install next@latest
```

Comment: TY @juliomalves, your insight here is quite helpful 

Answer (score 2):

actually i have got same problem/warning ,

and in my case i am using "react-toastify" inside my next.js application with context api,
and after a lot of searching ...

i found the problem coming from :

```
toast.configure() method
```

and i am use it inside my context api module ,
and also i found the official "react-toastify" Docs talking about some problems related with this method when use it with context api , and they are removed this method from the new version  .

and here is the link for official docs:

https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/migration-v9#toastconfigure-removal

finally i solved my problem by using the following steps :

1-remove toast.configure() from my context api module .

2- instead of using toast.configure() , i used "ToastContainer" component inside "_app" module "just define it , the toast will works fine" as expected , and here is my "_app.js module " :

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import '../styles/globals.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Nav from '../components/nav';
import Footer from '../components/footer'; 
import { AuthProvider } from '../my_utils/myContext/authcontext';



import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

    useEffect(() => {
        import ('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')
        import ('react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css')
    }, []);


    return (
    <> 
    <AuthProvider> 
        <Nav />
        <div className="allButFooter ms-3 me-3"> 
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            <ToastContainer />

        </div>
        <Footer />
    </AuthProvider>
    </>
    )
}
export default MyApp
```

i don't know if your case same my case ,
but i hope that helpful for you .

Answer (score 0):

just run that command to get the latest react version

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

Comment: didn't work. These version were already installed.

The app is 4 days old.