# Next.js (React 18) not working with HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, ssl, https, next.js, react-18

I'm upgraded my existing **Next.js** project to **React 18**. Everything ok in **http local server** but im trying to run project with **ssl**.

Now im getting this error

> Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

Also it works with no problem in **React 17**

**server.js** file

```
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');
const fs = require('fs');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./src/certificates/localhost-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./src/certificates/localhost.pem')
};
app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
        handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }).listen(3000, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('>>>>>> Server works with SSL on localhost:3000');
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be just a warning and they have a fallback to 17, any other errors ?

Comment: Yes, it seems it's just a warning on localhost. I have deployed project to netlify and warning dissapeared. Thanks @Ramakay

Comment: The warning doesn't seem related to using HTTPS, it's most likely related to this issue in Next.js: [Next js, ReactDom.render is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72145314/1870780).